# Dynamicly add/remove form elements w/ mysql support

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, dynamic

I'm trying to create page where the user can add & delete "soliders".

I'm looking for something like this:

```
[Text-box][Delete]
[Text-box][Delete]
[Add-Solider]
```

And I want it to support mysql, so the user can change the values later.
I've been searching, but i can't seem to find any with mysql-support.
It should also have a max-amount.

Have any of you dealt with something similar before? I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give here an example for Add and Remove elements.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Add Element</title>
<script language="javascript">
this.num = 1;
function addElement(){
$top = document.getElementById('top');
newId = document.createElement('div');
id = 'my'+this.num;
newId.setAttribute('id', id );
newId.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0); ' onclick='removedThis( "+id +")' >Added Element"+id+"</a>";
$top.appendChild(newId);
this.num++;
}
function removedThis( id ){
var d = document.getElementById('top');
d.removeChild(id);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Add Element" onclick="addElement()" />
<div id="top" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference: [javascript/php/mysal](http://yajukumar.wordpress.com/tag/add-element-thorugh-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

I give here an example of jQuery. Then you can save `<div id="boxes">` into mysql and induce again.

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#add_new").click(function () {
            var box = $("<div>[Text-box]<a class=\"del\" href=\"javascript:void;\">[Delete]</a></div>");
            $("#boxes").append(box);
            $(box).find(".del").click(function () {
                $(box).remove();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="boxes"></div>
<button id="add_new">[Add-Solider]</button>
```